# ReactNative: how to refresh on data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to React Native code building.
Below is my React Native code to get data from Firebase.

```
const page_one = () => {
   const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
   const [placeList, setPlaceList] = useState([])
   const [message, setMessage] = useState(false)

   const db = firebase.firestore().collection('places')

    const onLoad = async () => {

        const place_ref = await firebase.firestore().collection('places').get()
        if (place_ref.empty) {
            setMessage(true)
            return
        }

        const places = []
        try {
            place_ref.forEach(doc => {
                const entity = doc.data()
                entity.id = doc.id
                places.push(entity)
            })
            setPlaceList(places)
            setMessage(false)
            setIsLoading(false)
            return
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error:\n", error.message)
            return
        }
    }

}

    useEffect(() => {
        onLoad()
        console.log('place List')
    }, [isLoading])

return (<View></View>)

}
```

I need to refresh the current component every time I render, to get newly added data from firebase. How to make possible this.
As of now component is not loading when I rendering the component 2nd time. it fetches the old data only, not loading the latest data still I refreshing the whole application.

I need to fetch the latest data whenever I render the component.

I tried with below useEffect hook:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        onLoad()
        console.log('place List')
    }, [isLoading, placeList])
```

But it calls the firebase request n number of times till I existing the current component.

I want to call the firebase request only once when ever I visiting the current component.

please help me..

Comment: what you mean visiting 2nd component? you mean navigation ?

Comment: @prasanth I mean, need to get fresh data each time rendering the component.

Comment: As per you above code doesn't have any render activity in your return statement.it just ah plain view. if you need a refresh based on render please add the render state variable on `useffect` dependencies. like `,[loading,renderingStateValue]` . each time of updating `renderingStateValue` value then load function will be executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you need to refresh whenever this component gets focused

So for that, write like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
    onLoad() // Gets fired whenever this screen is in focus
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation]);
```

Also don't forget to destructure the props to get the `navigation` prop

Like this

```
const page_one = ({ navigation }) => {
    ...Code Inside
}
```